# Diff of two similar big raw binary files

Tags: files, diff, binary, patch

Let's say I have a 4 GB file `abc` on my local computer. I have uploaded it to a distant server via SFTP, it took a few hours.

Now I have slightly modified the file (probably 50 MB maximum, but not consecutive bytes in this file) locally, and saved it into `abc2`. I also kept the original file `abc` on my local computer.

**How to compute a binary diff of `abc` and `abc2`?**

Applications:

- I could only send a `patch` file (probably max 100MB) to the distant server, instead of reuploading the whole `abc2` file (it would take a few hours again!), and recreate `abc2` on the distant server from `abc` and `patch` only.
- Locally, instead of wasting 8 GB to backup both `abc` and `abc2`, I could save only `abc` + `patch`, so it would take < 4100 MB only.

How to do this?

PS: for text, I know `diff`, but here I'm looking for something that could work for any raw binary format, it could  be zip files or executables or even other types of file.

PS2: If possible, I don't want to use `rsync` ; I know it can replicate changes between 2 computers in an efficient way (not resending data that has not changed), but here I really want to have a `patch` file, that is reproducible later if I have both `abc` and `patch`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the second application/issue, I would use a deduplicating backup program like `restic` or `borgbackup`, rather than trying to manually keep track of "patches" or diffs. The `restic` backup program allows you to back up directories from multiple machines to the same backup repository, deduplicating the backup data both amongst fragments of files from an individual machine as well as between machine.  (I have no user experience with `borgbackup`, so I can't say anything about that program.)

Calculating and storing a diff of the `abc` and `abc2` files can be done with `rsync`.

This is an example with `abc` and `abc2` being 153 MB.  The file `abc2` has been modified by overwriting the first 2.3 MB of the file with some other data:

```
$ ls -lh
total 626208
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel   153M Feb  3 16:55 abc
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel   153M Feb  3 17:02 abc2
```

We create out patch for transforming `abc` into `abc2` and call it `abc-diff`:

```
$ rsync --only-write-batch=abc-diff abc2 abc
```

```
$ ls -lh
total 631026
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel   153M Feb  3 16:55 abc
-rw-------  1 kk  wheel   2.3M Feb  3 17:03 abc-diff
-rwx------  1 kk  wheel    38B Feb  3 17:03 abc-diff.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel   153M Feb  3 17:02 abc2
```

The generated file `abc-diff` is the actual diff (your "patch file"), while `abc-diff.sh` is a short shell script that `rsync` creates for you:

```
$ cat abc-diff.sh
rsync --read-batch=abc-diff ${1:-abc}
```

This script modifies `abc` so that it becomes identical to `abc2`, given the file `abc-diff`:

```
$ md5sum abc abc2
be00efe0a7a7d3b793e70e466cbc53c6  abc
3decbde2d3a87f3d954ccee9d60f249b  abc2
$ sh abc-diff.sh
$ md5sum abc abc2
3decbde2d3a87f3d954ccee9d60f249b  abc
3decbde2d3a87f3d954ccee9d60f249b  abc2
```

The file `abc-diff` could now be transferred to wherever else you have `abc`. With the command `rsync --read-batch=abc-diff abc`, you would apply the patch to the file `abc`, transforming its contents to be the same as the `abc2` file on the system where you created the diff.

Re-applying the patch a second time seems safe.  There is no error messages nor does the file's contents change (the MD5 checksum does not change).

Note that unless you create an explicit "reverse patch", there is no way to easily undo the application of the patch.

---

I also tested writing the 2.3 MB modification to some other place in the `abc2` data, a bit further in (at about 50 MB), as well as at the start.  The generated "patch" was 4.6 MB large, suggesting that only the modified bits were stored in the patch.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kusalananda, it's great! PS: `rsync --read-batch=abc-diff ${1:-abc}` (automatically generated .sh script) gave `remote destination is not allowed with --read-batch` `rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1326) [Receiver=3.1.2]`, but `rsync --read-batch=abc-diff abc` worked succesfully. What is the difference between these two similar commands?

Comment: 2/2 Is there a way to take `abc` as input, apply the patch `diff-abc` with `--read-batch` but not modify `abc` "in-place", but rather output to a new file `abc3`? (if possible all with `rsync`, without piping, so that it will work easily on Linux as well as Windows which also has `rsync.exe` available)

Comment: @Basj The commands would do different things if `$1` had a value. `${1:-abc}` means "use the first positional parameter (`$1`) unless it's empty or undefined. In the case that it's empty or undefined, use `abc` instead".  I'm assuming that `$1` _had_ a value when you tried it, possibly something that it interpreted as a remote destination address.

Comment: @Basj I'm not entirely sure that this is possible, but I'll have a look tomorrow after sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your answer about `${1:-abc}`. It probably failed is because I tried it on Windows (I'm using rsync both on Linux for my distant server, and Windows locally). But it's perfect since `rsync --read-batch=abc-diff abc` works :)

Answer (score 4):

> *How to compute a binary diff of abc and abc2?*

Using [bsdiff/bspatch](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) or xdelta and others.

```
$ bsdiff older newer patch.bin     # patch.bin is created
[...]
$ bspatch older newer patch.bin    # newer is created
```

However, these admonishments from the man pages are to be noted:

- `bsdiff` uses memory equal to 17 times the size of *oldfile*, and requires an absolute minimum working set size of 8 times the size of *oldfile*.
- `bspatch` uses memory equal to the size of *oldfile* plus the size of *newfile*, but can tolerate a very small working set without a dramatic
   loss of performance.

Comment: Could you possibly show an example?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `bsdiff uses memory equal to 17 times the size of oldfile` so this won't usually work for 4GB files (at least on my 8GB RAM machine).

Comment: @Basj What is possible is to chop up the 4GB file into smaller ones (say 128MB each), and do individual deltas. This could be wrapped into a script. chopped-bsdiff: chop the files, do pairwise bsdiffs, tar those up into an archive. chopped-bspatch: read pairwise patches from archive, apply to chunks of input file, catenate output.

Comment: @Kaz I see, but I'm more looking for a ready-to-use tool that can be called in 1 line (`mydiff abc abc2 > patchfile` and `mypatch abc patchfile > abc3`) regardless the size. Also, if I chop into 128 MB chunks, what happens if the first 1GB of `abc` == the last (trailing) 1GB of `abc2`? When we'll compare `abc-first128mb` with `abc2-first128mb`, no match will be found, so it might not be efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just forcing `diff` to treat the files as text:

```
diff -ua abc abc2
```

As explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Binary.html).

- `-u` output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context
- `-a` treat all files as text

This should get you a patch. The downside of this is the 'lines' could be quite long and that could bloat the patch.

Comment: Oops, yeah you don't actually want the `n`. I'm interested to know if it works as I'm not sure how long the "lines" will be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I created two very similar 256 MB files `abc` and `abc2`. Then I tried `diff -ua abc abc2 > patch`, then I copied `abc` to `abc3` and I tried to recover `abc2` thanks to `abc3` and `patch` : `patch abc3 < patch`, but it did not work: at the end `abc3` was only 1KB instead of 256 MB. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what happened. I just did it on my machine and it worked better than I had expected. I took a 382M file that was random integers written out in binary to a file. I changed 3 bytes in it and did the diff and patch and it worked. The resulting files were md5sum equal.

Comment: If a big file has no byte `0x0a`, i.e. newline, or very few, I suspect it wouldn't work so well, it would be interesting to test.

Comment: Oh for sure. You can make an educated guess on a binary with `wc -l` which will look for line breaks and in my experience runs very quickly. I would expect on a arbitrary binary it would work pretty well. For example on my machine I found a 252M mp4 that had 1.2 million "lines", and a 59M `.deb` that had about 230k, so average "lines" of less than 220 bytes and 258 bytes respectively. I don't see why these files would be that different than others but you could definitely get unlucky. In practice I suspect that it would work pretty well and if not it's still a fun hack.

Answer (score 1):

Use [xdelta](http://xdelta.org), it was created exactly for this type of uses. Based on VCDIFF (RFC 3284) in latest versions.

Comment: The link is non-working (is there another URL?). Also could you add an example in a few lines to show how to: 1) compute the diff `patch` file, and 2) restore `abc2`, given only `abc` and `patch`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed URL

Comment: Thanks @vonbrand. Would you have such an example?

Answer (score 0):

Complements to other answers according to my tests:

#### With `diff`

I created two very similar 256 MB files `abc` and `abc2`. Then let's create the diff file:

```
diff -ua abc abc2 > abc-abc2.diff
```

Now let's try to recover `abc2` thanks to the original `abc` file and `abc-abc2.diff`:

```
cp abc abc3
patch abc3 < abc-abc2.diff
```

or

```
cp abc abc3
patch abc3 -i abc-abc2.diff
```

or

```
patch abc -i abc-abc2.diff -o abc3
```

It works on Linux. I also tried on Windows (patch.exe and diff.exe are available too), but for an unknown reason it failed: the produced `abc3` file is only 1KB instead of 256MB (I'll update this answer later here).

### With `rsync`

As detailed in the accepted answer, this works:

```
rsync --only-write-batch=abc-abc2-diff abc2 abc

cp abc abc3

rsync --read-batch=abc-abc2-diff abc3
```

#### With `rdiff`

As detailed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/283008/binary-diff-patch-for-large-files-on-linux/1523459#1523459), this is a solution too:

```
rdiff signature abc abc-signature
rdiff delta abc-signature abc2 abc-abc2-delta

rdiff patch abc abc-abc2-delta abc3
```

Tested also on Windows with rdiff.exe from [here](https://www.timedicer.co.uk/rdiff.php) and it works.

Comment: I'm guessing that patch failed on Windows because it was reading the input file in"text" mode which signals end-of-file when it encounters a CONTROL-Z (byte 0x18) in the input file.  This is a legacy mode from early DOS days when the directory did not record the length of the file and so the file-length was computed based on the number of 512-byte sectors. If you can tell `patch` to open the file in binary mode, it shouldn't have this error.