# How does rsync work in this simple example?

Tags: rsync, diff

Let's say:

- `a` is a 256 MB file containing random bytes
- `b` is the **same file** except it has one additional leading byte `0`

Thanks to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565559/diff-of-two-similar-big-raw-binary-files/565566#565566), I discovered that `rsync` is able to compute a "binary diff patch" between these two files:

```
rsync --only-write-batch=patch b a
```

In this example, the `patch` file is ... only 65 KB, so it's very good.

**In short, how did `rsync` detect so few byes were changed?** I initially thought it would compare:

- a[0:k] and b[0:k]
- a[k+1:2k] and b[k+1:2k]
- a[2k+1:3k] and b[2k+1:3k]
- ...
- a[N-k:N] and b[N-k:N]

for various values of k, e.g. the biggest power of 2 possible (2^j), then if no match, 2^(j-1), then 2^(j-2), etc.

But for these files `a` and `b`, it would totally fail because since `b` is just `a` shifted of one byte, there would be no similar chunks at all! Then we would expect the `patch` to be ... 256 MB.

But here it works in a more clever way, how did the algorithm work in this simple example `b` = a byte concatenated with the content of `a` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps someone who knows this better can post another answer, but after further research, the key in rsync algorithm seems to be detailed in the paragraph ["Determining which parts of a file have changed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Determining_which_parts_of_a_file_have_changed): [Rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash).

Another useful reading: https://moinakg.wordpress.com/tag/rolling-hash/

[image]

vs. :

[image]

---

Another useful resource: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/rsync/overview.html