# What command will give me a binary delta between two files and let me apply it?

Tags: files, hashsum

I have two large files.

- `a.qcow2` is 16GB.
- `b.qcow2` is 17GB.

The first 16GB of `b.qcow2` is 95% identical to `a.qcow2`.

What Linux commands will let me produce the delta between the two files?  (Which should be less than 2GB in size.)

What linux commands will let me apply the delta to `a.qcow2` to produce output identical to `b.qcow2`?

Do the delta formats have safety measures, such as the source and target sizes and hashes?

Comment: Look at [`qemu-img rebase`](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/tools/qemu-img.html). And do not use pointlessly general titles.

Comment: To create a delta/diff between two _generic_ files using `rsync`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565566/116858

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to have two similar VMs what i recommend you is using qemu option: backing_file

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 \
                -o backing_file=/path/to/base/image.qcow2 \
                /path/to/new_guest/image.qcow2
```

What this allows you it's to have a master image and then only a differential file  between the original and the seccond, saving you a lot of GB.
Also if you really need to know the binary difference between this files i recommend you to checkout the following commands:

- rdiff
- dhex
- xdelta

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you want to transport the difference between two systems, and this is why you can't rebase your QCOW images on a shared root.

The `rsync` tool will let you generate a binary difference. Here's a worked example with (considerably) smaller files

```
ls -l ?.qcow2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 76993536 Jan  2  2020 a.qcow2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 77337600 Oct 25 19:00 b.qcow2
```

As per your question, we need to get the differences from `b.qcow2` to `a.qcow2`. Note that provided `rsync` can get to both source and destination there is no need for them to be on the same server

```
rsync -av --only-write-batch b_to_a.rsyncdiff b.qcow2 a.qcow2
```

This determines the difference and writes it to `b_to_a.rsyncdiff`, also creating a helper shellscript along the way

```
ls -l b_to_a*
-rw------- 1 root root 35617731 Oct 26 09:26 b_to_a.rsyncdiff
-rwx------ 1 root root       54 Oct 26 09:26 b_to_a.rsyncdiff.sh

cat b_to_a.rsyncdiff.sh
rsync -av --read-batch b_to_a.rsyncdiff ${1:-a.qcow2}
```

To apply the change you just need the original source `a.qcow2` and the diff

```
rsync -av --read-batch b_to_a.rsyncdiff a.qcow2
receiving incremental file list
b.qcow2

sent 61,509 bytes  received 35,621,188 bytes  71,365,394.00 bytes/sec
total size is 77,337,600  speedup is 2.17
```

Result

```
ls -l ?.qcow2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 77337600 Oct 25 19:00 a.qcow2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 77337600 Oct 25 19:00 b.qcow2
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'm a huge fan of [deltup](https://github.com/jjwhitney/Deltup) which is well known only among Gentoo users.

It's very fast and too often beats `xdelta` by a large margin.

Comment: How would it be used here?

Comment: https://github.com/jjwhitney/Deltup -> "You may also use Deltup manually.  Here are some examples of it's use:"